# gedit code to embed current date within the file

Tags: gedit

Does the gedit editor have a code to automatically embed the current date when I save a file?
I don't always remember to edit my "last updated" comment in the file.

Comment: I am aware of https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-plugins-insert-date-time.html.en edit/insert date and time, but that inserts a text string.  I need a "code" to be inserted which will be interpreted at the time the file is saved.

Comment: Please edit your question with the new information / explanations. `gedi` is a text editor, what kind of "code" are you trying to edit? The inserted "code" would depend on the language the "code" is written in. Gedit cannot edit binary code.

Comment: I was looking for something like WordPerfect had which would enter today's date and time at the point in the document where you indicated it should appear.  Each time you save the file, it updates the date/time in the document itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the gedit editor have a code to automatically embed the current date when I save a file?

I have gedit 3.28.1 and am not aware of such a code.

The following script inserts a timestamp into your file as the last line at the time you save the file with plain text editors such as gedit or geany and for LibreOffice Writer **on x11**. I don't use Wayland.

You'll need to install *xdotool* and *xsel*.

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 0.1 && xdotool key ctrl+End Return;

sleep 0.1 && date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | tr -d "\n" | xsel -i -b;

sleep 0.1 && xdotool key "ctrl+v";

sleep 0.1 && xdotool key "Alt+F4";

exit
```

I saved the script as *add-timestamp.sh* in *~/bin*, made it executable, and assigned <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> as its keyboard shortcut.

My laptop is a bit aged; maybe the various *sleep* entries aren't needed on a faster machine.

Credit to http://www.arcadien.net/node/48

[image: animation to illustrate adding timestamp]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do it in gedit, but I found a way to do it with PHP.  Since I wanted the functionality for my web page files anyway, the PHP option works for me.  To make my individual pages display the date/time that they were last edited, I add this line of code to the page's source:

Last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", getlastmod()) . ""; ?>

Works for me.
Also, CK Bose' answer looks like a good solution.  Thanks, DK Bose!