# gedit: is there a keyboard shortcut in gedit itself to insert date and time?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit

Note: I'm interested in knowing if there's a shortcut **native to gedit itself**. I'm not interested in solutions involving Autokey, etc.

In gedit 3.28.1 (Ubuntu 18.04) and 3.30.0 (Ubuntu 19.04), if I want to insert the date and time (assuming the corresponding plugin is active), I need to

1. Click on Menu (☰)
2. Click on Tools
3. Click on Insert Date and Time …
4. Click on Insert

[This page](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en) doesn't list a keyboard shortcut even to get directly to step #3 in the list above.

(I know there are other ways such as using xdotool and xsel to insert time and date.)

Comment: @Graham, I've clarified that I'm not interested in alternatives. I want to know whether **gedit itself** has a keyboard shortcut. BTW, I think AutoKey constantly runs in the background. You should look at [texpander](https://github.com/leehblue/texpander) which runs only on demand. An example is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1075019/248158).

Comment: This question is very justified. Gedit provides a function to insert a date, but apparently wants to make it as difficult as possible to use it. This is a valid issue for Gedit that should be filed if it hasn't already..

Comment: Ok. I've retracted the close vote accordingly. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Probably you might find [this](https://ratil.life/keyboard-timestamp-in-gedit/) useful, looks like a pretty native solution.

Comment: Most useful! I'm trying it out now. If you post an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: @mook765, I'm struggling to understand the GUI! I posted an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1168099/248158) earlier on a related question.

Comment: Click + in bottom left. Rename "New tool" to provide a name you want. Now edit the code: the bash "shebang" is already filled in for you (first line). In its simpest form, add a second line "date". Under "Shortcut key", supply your hotkey. Under "Output", select "Insert at cursor position". No saving needed: just close the dialog when done. Pressing the hotkey now should insert the date as provided by the date command.

Comment: @vanadium I got it working but if you want, please post an answer.

Comment: All right, I have some time left ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Gedit click the cog-wheel and choose `Preferences`

Open the `Plugin`-tab  and enable `External Tools`.

Close the `Preferences`-window and click the cog-wheel again, you will find the option
`Manage External Tools...` now, select it to open the `Manage External Tools`-window:

[image]

Click the `+` button to add a new function and give it a name, add the `date`-command with the options of your choice, click the `Shortcut key`-button and assgin a shortcut and in the `Output`-field choose `Insert at cursor position` from the drop-down-menu.

Close the `Manage External Tools`-window and test the new keyboard-shortcut in the main gedit window.

Reference: [Timestamp Keyboard Shortcut In gedit](https://ratil.life/keyboard-timestamp-in-gedit/)

Comment: It adds a newline as well. It would be cool if instead it adds ":"

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the accepted answer, I have put together a GitHub project with some additional information and a Gedit extension file that can be directly downloaded and then copy/pasted into location -

https://github.com/harrison-broadbent/gedit-insert-date

Hope anyone stumbling on this finds this project useful!

Comment: Excellent and elegant.
I preferred the manual method.
Thank you for posting.